# Variable not being assigned in vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table I am trying to use to do a vlookup in column2 of the table and get data from column8 in the table.  However, the variable will not be assigned. When the code gets to the variable indicated, proceed without assigning a variable and then skip the if statement altogether. I don't get an error, the code just proceeds as though its not there. Can someone tell me why this variable isn't being assigned data from the vlookup

```
Option Explicit
Dim RevSID As String
Dim RevSupLev As String
Dim RevActive As String
Dim DueDate As Date



Private Sub Contact_Update()
Set CaseRng = CaseRevPvt.DataBodyRange *Another pivot table in the workbook
Set Contact = Worksheets("Tables").ListObjects("Contact") 

 For Each cell In CaseRng

    RevSID = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    RevSupLev = cell.Offset(0, 2)
    RevActive = cell.Offset(0, 3)

    If RevSID = 0 Then 'An integer variable function doesn't need to run if no data
        On Error Resume Next
        End If  

    elseif RevActive = "No" then
         'Do stuff..works fine
    elseif RevSupLev = "String indicated" then
        if PADate>duedate then 'checks PADue for condition
             'does stuff, this works
        else: Call StandRev 'the intent is to do a Vlookup using RevSID,
                'find the matching data in Column2 of the Contact table and assign the
                information in Column8 to lastrev
```

---

```
Private Sub StandRev()
Dim VlookUp As Range
Dim lastrev As Date


With Worksheets("Tables") 'sets a look up range within the table "Contact"
Set VlookUp = Contact.Parent.Range(Contact.ListColumns("SID").DataBodyRange, Contact.ListColumns("Last Review").DataBodyRange)

lastrev = Application.WorksheetFunction.VlookUp(RevSID, VlookUp, 8,False)  '*** problem here -- RevSID variable is assigned in previous sub
' no data is saved in variable, program ends sub

If lastrev > AttempDate2 Then
    'code that will replace lastrev with data in AttempDate2, AttempDate2 varaiable assigned in another sub
End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not pass `RevSID` as a parameter instead of having it up in the air? `Private Sub StandRev(ByVal RevSID As String)`; the caller can then do `StandRev "the value"`.

Comment: What is `Contact`, and why isn't that `With` block used?

Comment: I don't understand. RevSID is a variable string, an ID-number of sorts for employees. It's not up in the air. What is the difference between a parameter and a variable?

Comment: Scope. The tighter a variable's scope, the better. If everything is global state, you're going to end up dealing with global state -related bugs, and you don't want to be dealing with those. Variables very rarely ever *need* to be global. And testability. You can test a parameterized procedure much more easily than one that depends on some state that's not obviously needed by that procedure.

Comment: `VlookUp` try not to use variable names close to VBA's own

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `VlookUp` isn't a reserved name though. All it does is mess up the casing of `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` ;-)

Comment: Contact is the name of a table on the workbook. My intent is for the with block to state the worksheet being used. Most of the code is done on a different worksheet but the part requires getting information and adding information to a different worksheet.

Comment: I am trying to read on parameters but I'm not understanding how it would stop assigning a value to lastrev variable. RevSID is a variable with data assigned it when this sub function runs.

Comment: And that makes the procedure be not self-contained, relying on state that is outside its scope - which makes us ask a bunch of clarifying questions about what's what, because the state isn't enclosed in the procedure. Parameters help make the code clearer & cleaner, and essentially remove the need for global state. It's not about `lastRev` and the bug you're having, it's about clarity of the code and the ability of others to understand what's going on.

Comment: Have you stripped an `On Error Resume Next` statement by any chance? `WorksheetFunction.Whatever` will raise a run-time error when the function fails. The assignment "not working", and "not getting any errors" are contradicting statements. Verify the VBE settings for error handling: is it set to "break on unhandled errors"? Execution jumping out of the procedure very much points to an error happening here. IOW the vlookup is returning `#N/A`, and you're getting a type mismatch error trying to assign that to a `Date` variable.

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought I did that with the comment to the side of the bit of code  with the RevSID. I added that comment because the RevSID variable isn't defined in this particular function. As far as I can tell, all variables not assigned here are assigned in the submodules accordingly and that data carries over to this module.

Comment: What do you mean by "stripping an On Error Resume Next"? There is an "On Error Resume Next" else where but if StandRev runs, the "On Error Resume Next" conditions were not met. I don't know where I said the assignment was not working, I meant that no data is assigned to a variable and I get no error when it doesn't. RevSID is not a date value, but the data I am looking for with the VLookup is a date.

Comment: "no data is assigned to a variable" means the assignment isn't working, and that is impossible without a runtime error being raised, hence my asking whether OERN was maybe deemed irrelevant and removed from the post, as it happens all the time.

Comment: The fact that these comments are turning into a discussion about "WTH is RevSID?" is the perfect illustration of why you should consider passing things like that as parameters instead of relying on a bunch of global variables. If you can't look at a procedure this short and easily determine how it will behave, that's a problem - maybe not now, but in 6 months when you're trying to maintain this.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that sets a value to `RevSID`?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not very familiar with parameters and since RevSID data is assigned, I don't really understand why it's a focus or how it's causing the vlookup to not assign a value to lastrev. I updated with the code that leads into this sub for more context.

Comment: See, `RevSID = cell.Offset(0, 1)` is assigning `RevSID` to some `Range.Value`, through an implicit default member call. Seeing how `RevSID` isn't declared anywhere (you should *really* specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module), that means `RevSID` is a `Variant` with a subtype that depends on the contents of that cell - *maybe* a `String`, *maybe* something else. Could be a `Variant/Error` for all we know. With a properly defined parameter, if the value isn't a string then code fails much faster & closer to the source of the problem, since the procedure can't even be invoked.

Comment: Option explicit is used and RevSID a string value. I don't have an issue with RevSID assignment anywhere in the code, even the code that I originally posted. I don't want to copy and past the code for the entire worksheet since it's kinda long and all of it has worked fine until I added the code I originally had questions about.

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, the module is triggered by a button click and depending on the information different procedures are triggered. There are there are three main procedures and some sub procedures based on the main procedures. RevSID is a global variable since it is used in all procedures as it identifies the employee. If certain conditions are met during the Contact_Update procedure, then StandRev procedure will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `RevSID` wasn't declared explicitly, then the `RevSID` in procedure1 would not be the same variable as `RevSID` in procedure2: undeclared variables are always locally scoped, so assigning it in procedure2 wouldn't affect the value of the same-name variable in procedure1.

But that's not what's going on here. Since `RevSID` *is* declared somewhere, your lookup must be failing (i.e. it's not finding the `RevSID` value in the lookup table).

I'll suggest a wildly different approach, using a function instead, and a pattern known as the "try pattern", where you have a function that returns a `Boolean` and outputs a result in a parameter that's passed by reference, that only has a meaningful value when the function returns `True` - and since at a glance it appears that the `[SID]` column isn't the left-most in the table (why would you be going all the way up to `Contact.Parent` otherwise?), I'll suggest using a combination of INDEX and MATCH to perform the lookup - notice how the order of the columns becomes irrelevant with this lookup approach.

Here's a version with early-bound `WorksheetFunction` calls, which raise a run-time error upon failure:

```
Private Function TryGetRevisionDate(ByVal SID As String, ByRef outResult As Date) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Dim matchRow As Long
        matchRow = .Match(SID, Contact.ListColumns("SID").DataBodyRange, 0)

        Dim indexValue As Variant
        indexValue = .Index(Contact.ListColumns("Last Review").DataBodyRange, matchRow)
    End With

    If IsDate(indexValue) Then outResult = indexValue
    TryGetRevisionDate = True

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    'lookup failed
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

And a version with late-bound `WorksheetFunction` calls, which *return* an error value upon failure (note that you get no parameter info, and no compile-time validation with late-bound code, so watch out for typos - `Option Explicit` can't save you here):

```
Private Function TryGetRevisionDate(ByVal SID As String, ByRef outResult As Date) As Boolean
    With Application

        Dim matchRow As Variant
        matchRow = .Match(SID, Contact.ListColumns("SID").DataBodyRange, 0)
        If IsError(matchRow) Then Exit Function

        Dim indexValue As Variant
        indexValue = .Index(Contact.ListColumns("Last Review").DataBodyRange, matchRow)
        If IsError(indexValue) Then Exit Function

    End With

    If IsDate(indexValue) Then
        outResult = indexValue
        TryGetRevisionDate = True
    End If

End Function
```

Using either version, your calling code can now do this:

```
Dim revDate As Date
If TryGetRevisionDate(RevSID, revDate) Then
    MsgBox revDate
Else
    MsgBox "SID '" & RevSID & "' was not found."
End If
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter, but when I put a watch on RevSID while the StandRev procedure is running, the correct data is there meaning that the variable assignment that occurred during the Contact_Update procedure carries over to the StandRev procedure.

Comment: Your patience and help is much appreciated. For anyone that comes to read this later, this code works but for some reason, the match is not finding the data on the table set. So the issue is the data enter in the variable or on the data. I'm gonna try and approach this issue with a different question.

Comment: @MsAgentM no problem - before you ask, make sure you verify the data in the table doesn't have leading or trailing spaces: that's a common cause for failing lookups.